# TYPO3 mm relation modify foreign_sorting programmatically

Tags: php, sorting, typo3, extbase

I'm trying to sort an mm-relation programmatically in FrontEnd. Does anyone know how to do this?

I have 3 tables table_1, table_2 and the relation-table table1_table2_mm

how am I able to modify the sorting for the relation-table in Extbase?

Comment: I‘m not sure what you want to achieve. I suppose you want to retrieve or show sorted relations in front end while managing sorting from back end, don‘t you? And in back end you want to sort relation by drag-and-drop (e.g. via IRRE) or those tiny arrows.

Comment: Hello, sorting should be done in frontend. i want do have the tiny arrows funcionality in frontend.

i managed it with $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->execUPDATEquery .....

but is there a better way?

thanks

Comment: Ah, I see. Never tried that. I doubt there‘s an Extbase way of doing so :-( but I‘d like to be proven wrong…

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change sorting (which should be located in the MM table) you need to update every item in this MM relation. In the BE the sorting for each item of this relation will be re-calculated.

Example:

```
Item 1 => sorting 0
Item 4 => sorting 250
Item 5 => sorting 500
Item 3 => sorting 750
Item 2 => sorting 1000
```

If you want to move Item 3 to the second place, you need to calculate sorting for every Item after it:

```
Item 1 => sorting 0
Item 3 => sorting 250
Item 4 => sorting 500
Item 5 => sorting 750
Item 2 => sorting 1000
```